# Direct stderr to stdout $ command-name 2>&1 Doesn't stderr get printed to the terminal by default?

Tags: linux, bash

The error message always gets printed to the terminal whenever I get an error in bash shell (e.g. poor syntax)

```
$ totem Desktop/songs/song1.mp3
** Message: Error: Resource not found.
gstfilesrc.c(1055): gst_file_src_start (): /GstPlayBin2:play/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstFileSrc:source:
No such file "/home/me/Desktop/songs/song1.mp3"
```

So what is the purpose of redirecting stderr to stdout if stderr gets printed to terminal by default?

```
$ command-name 2>&1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, both `stdout` and `stderr` are directed to the terminal. If you redirect `stderr` to `stdout`, then it also goes to the terminal.

If you want to get rid of the stderr output, redirect it to the void:

```
$ command-name 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: @ Didier Trosset.  Thanks! So why would I want to redirect stderr to stdout, ever?

Comment: @LedZeppelin: if you want both the output and the error to be logged in the same file ;) that is not something i'd do, but situation may demand it

Comment: Can't you redirect both output and error to the same file with `$ command1 &> errorAndOutput`?

Comment: @LedZeppelin: You have to redirect first `stdout` with `> whatever`, and then redirect `stderr` to the new `stdout` with `2>&1`. Order matters: `$ command >whatever 2>&1`

Comment: So you can't redirect both output and error to the same file with `$ command1 &> errorAndOutput`?

Comment: @LedZepplin: Yes you can: `$ command1 > errorAndOutput 2>&1` Will redirect both into the same file.

Comment: @LedZeppelin: `&>` is a [Bashism](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism#Redirections), but a very useful one.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `stdout` gets printed to the terminal by default. and by doing `command-name 2>&1` you are essentially redirecting `stderr` to the same place.

Also order of redirection matters.

So what you are looking for is , `command-name >file_for_stdout 2>&1`

Answer (score 1):

`stderr` and `stdout` are by default both displayed on the controlling terminal. If you multiplex them as you've done, they will both be output on the whatever `stdout` outputs to. You can then redirect `stdout` to a file to get output and errors in a single file.

```
$ command >log 2>&1
```

will put both errors and output into the file called `log.